# Sql server and Asp.net closing connection does not close the Sql Server Session

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-pooling

I'm using an Asp.NET Web Application with MSSQL Server.
In my page i open a connection and i close it at the end of page.
But in Sql Analyzer the Sql session is still there, giving me after some amount of time a connection pool limits exceed error.
Sessions are cleared only when i shutdown the webserver.

Can someone explain how to fix this?
Thanks

This is the code i'm using:

```
Conn = new SqlConnection(StrConn);
Conn.Open();

.....

Conn.Close(); // In the debugger i can see connection state = closed
Conn = null;
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's opening and closing the connection.

Comment: Most likely connection pooling issue - try adding `Pooling=false` to the connection string. What happens?

Comment: Might need some more detail than that...  Where is the connection opened, where is it closed?  How is the open called?

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard you are legend. Thanks a lot man, I just added that magic parameter in the connection string and now it works as it should.

Comment: @ShadyOverflow huh, lol.... so much time passed. Will post this as answer. Thanks for the reminder! (I know you're not the OP. ;))

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a connection pooling issue.

Add `Pooling=false` to the connection string, and the database won't keep the connection open.